# Save list of objects to redis using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I created the RedisConfig class, which conatins Beans `JedisConnectionFactory` and `RedisTemplate`. `RedisTemplate` look like this:

```
@Bean
RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    final RedisTemplate< String, Object > template =  new RedisTemplate< String, Object >();
    template.setConnectionFactory( jedisConnectionFactory() );
    template.setKeySerializer( new StringRedisSerializer() );
    template.setHashValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );
    template.setValueSerializer( new GenericToStringSerializer< Object >( Object.class ) );
    return template;
}
```

My `pom.xml` contains:

```
   <!--  Spring Boot Redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I created the service, when i get a list of objects:

```
@Service
public class YandexMapsService {
    @Autowired
    private final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    // something

    public List<ResultGeoObjectDto> getGeographicCoordinates(String geoParam) {
    List<ResultGeoObjectDto> resultGeoObjectDto = new ArrayList<>();
    yandexMapsRestApiClient.getGeographicObject(geoParam).forEach((GeoObjectDto geoItem) -> {
        resultGeoObjectDto.add(geoConverterService.convertToResultGeoObjectDto(geoItem));
    });
    return resultGeoObjectDto;
    }
}
```

Before return, I want save `resultGeoObjectDto` to `Redis` as value, key is `geoParam`.

How I can do it? Thank

**UPDATE:**
I try:

```
redisTemplate.opsForList(geoParam, resultGeoObjectDto);
```

But, I have error:

```
 Error:(33, 22) java: method opsForList in class org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate<K,V> cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: 
java.lang.String,java.util.List<ru.geo.converter.model.ResultGeoObjectDto>
```

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: How about to save your list using: opsForList(), secondly I would change RedisTemplate<String, Object> to RedisTemplate<String, String> and I would save JSON String in that list.

Comment: @MosheArad, I try `redisTemplate.opsForList(geoParam, resultGeoObjectDto);`, but I've error: `Error:(33, 22) java: method opsForList in class org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate<K,V> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String,java.util.List<ru.geo.converter.model.ResultGeoObjectDto>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Comment: what about: leftPush(K key, V value) , you should do it like this: redisTemplate.opsForList(). leftPush(geoParam, yourItemFromListValue)